# How to override customer resource module customer.php

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, override-model

I have override **customer resource** module in custom module.
Like : **Core_Mage_Model_Resource_Customer**
Override this module but not succeed.
I have follow these steps :
Here is **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Abc_CustomizeCustomers>
       <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Abc_CustomizeCustomers>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <customer_re>
          <rewrite> 
            <customer_resource> Abc_CustomizeCustomers_Model_Resource_Customer</customer_resource>
          </rewrite>
       </customer_re>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is **Customer.php**

```
 <?php
    class Abc_CustomizeCustomers_Model_Resource_Customer extends 
      Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
     {
         protected function _beforeSave(Varien_Object $customer)
         {
             Mage::log("checkCustomer", null, 'appServer.log');
         } 
     }
```

But when save customer. log file is not create.
I want to override **_beforeSave** Function.

Please anyone suggest me how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add **models** node and follow below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Abc_CustomizeCustomers>
       <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Abc_CustomizeCustomers>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <customer_resource>
            <rewrite> 
              <customer>Abc_CustomizeCustomers_Model_Resource_Customer</customer>
            </rewrite>
          </customer_resource>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And file will be   **extends** `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer`

```
<?php
    class Abc_CustomizeCustomers_Model_Resource_Customer extends 
      Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer
     {
         public function __construct()
         { echo "dsfsdfdsfsd"; exit;


         } 
     }
```

Second solution you can use event for that too **customer_save_before**

Comment: I am trying to these but not succeed.

Comment: @RakeshPatidar it is tested code i checked it is working now i update the php file too

Comment: @RakeshPatidar other option is use event `customer_save_before`